# Perf profiling shows wrong call-graph

Tags: stack, profiling, perf

I am trying to profile my code.
After running perf, the resulting flame graph looks like that:

[image]

The 30% left follows my program calling graph. The 70% on the right are various samples, which are incorrectly detached from the left 30%, as they are always called from these 30%.

So, the 30% left should in fact stretched to 100%, and the right 70% should be on top.

Why is perf loosing track of callers in stack at some point?

Comment: How did you run perf exactly, and how did you build?  Did you tell it to use frame-pointer backtraces and maybe some of your code wasn't built with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  Or if you weren't using frame-pointer backtraces, I think problems like this are why frame-pointer is recommended for perf.

Comment: Especially look at the function on the bottom of the stacks on the left. It's that function that is having problems being unwound. Try all the different call stack collection techniques: --call-graph [lbr, dwarf, fp].